# Define query param in app.yaml in Google Appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I would like to serve static files depending on the query parameter. More specificly I would like to serve prerendered snapshots for search engine optimalization. The pages are hosted on Google Appengine, so I'm using app.yaml to define these urls.

```
handlers:
# Consider anything matching a dot static content.
- url: /(.*\..*)$
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*\..*)$

# Serve snapshots for seo
- url: /?_escaped_fragment_=(.*)
  static_files: dist/snapshots/\1
  upload: dist/(.*)$

# Otherwise let Angular handle it.
- url: /(.*)
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
```

However, when I fetch a url with the query parameter `_escaped_fragment_`, the last url handler is triggered. Is it possible to define query params in urls? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the url you're trying to fetch?

Comment: Any url googlebot would fetch. For example I have `/support` defined, so  googlebot would fetch `/?_escaped_fragment_=support`. It is an AngularJS site, so `/?_escaped_fragment_=support` should fetch a prerendered html file in order to index it.

Comment: The workaround is create a handler which either returns dist/index.html (when _escape_fragment_ isn't in the query string) else returns snapshop html for the given _escape_fragment_. I don't know how much additional cost is involved with serving it this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm happy to be proven wrong, but I'm pretty sure that query parameters aren't considered when dispatching via `app.yaml`.

Comment: I was hoping to get an answer saying something else, but unfortunately I think this answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. It is kind of lame that App Engine hasn't added the ability to dispatch on static query parameters... Anyway.

```
import webapp2, urllib, logging, json, os

dp = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
fp = os.path.join(dp, "resources", 'index.html')
w = open(fp, 'r').read()

class Fragment(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, pathname):
    if '_escaped_fragment_' in self.request.arguments():
      CODE_GOES_HERE_FOR_BUILDING_YOUR_FRAGMENT_RESPONSE
    else:
      self.response.write(w)

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    [('/(.*)', Fragment)],
  debug=True)
```

This code basically guesses whether you are dispatching on the `_escaped_fragment_` query parameter and modifies the output accordingly. I have no idea how much less (if any) performant this is than being able to just leave `index.html` in the `static_files:` handlers in `app.yaml`.

Comment: I had built something similar back when I still had the problem. Nowadays Google indexes the JavaScript rendered pages, making the `_escaped_fragment_` responses less important. (Still useful for other search engines though.)

Comment: Good point. I unfortunately still have a dynamic site where the majority of content does not show up unless you use javascripting UI elements, so the _escaped_fragment_ thing is still useful in my particular case. But yes, I agree, if the majority of your content shows up on initial javascript render, then google probably handles that just fine.