# Python AppEngine - How to pass query strings in app.yaml

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

I'm trying to set different folders according to mobile platforms, but I can't figure it out how to do it.

Here's some code:

App.yaml

```
- url: /winners
  secure: always
  static_files: static_files/winners.json
  upload: static_files/winners.json
  http_headers:
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=latin-1
```

this works fine but when I set the query string like this:

```
- url: /winners?platform=android
  secure: always
  static_files: static_files/winners.json
  upload: static_files/winners.json
  http_headers:
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=latin-1
```

It does not!

I basically want to send different resources according to each platform, is this possible?

Thanks :)

ps: Similar question that says "no" to what I want to achieve [Define query param in app.yaml in Google Appengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018142/define-query-param-in-app-yaml-in-google-appengine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the answer to the question you referenced, query parameters are ignored when routing via `app.yaml`. But it is possible to offer different resources according to each platform, only using other mechanisms.

One approach could be by encoding the platform in the URL, but not as a query parameter, for example `/winners/android`, handled via this `app.yaml` routing:

```
- url: /winners/(.*)$
  secure: always
  static_files: static_files/\1/winners.json
  upload: static_files/\1/winners.json
  http_headers:
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=latin-1
```

Which would serve a file stored as `static_files/android/winners.json`

More details in [Static file pattern handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_pattern_handlers).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I checked another question related to mine and I think what you said is the way to go. :)